# Why this XMLHttpRequest doesn't work in IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a very simple XMLHttpRequest making a `POST` call. It works on Chrome and Firefox. But when I tried it in IE10, I got this error..

> SCRIPT5022: InvalidStateError

Here's the code.

```
function _ajaxHelper(options) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var opts = _extendHelper({
    withCredentials: false,
    method: 'GET'
  }, options);

  xhr.withCredentials = opts.withCredentials;
  xhr.open(opts.method, opts.url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'text/plain');
  xhr.send(JSON.stringify(options.data));

  return {
    done: function done(cb) {
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function onStateChange() {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
          if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 300) {
            cb(this.responseText);
          } else {
            cb(false);
          }
        }
      };

      xhr.ontimeout = function onTimeout() {
        cb(false);
      };

      xhr.onerror = function onError() {
        cb(false);
      };
    }
  };
}
```

From what I googled, the reason that I would get that error was I set `responseText` but I didn't set anything and I'm getting instead. So, not sure what I did wrong there.

For `_extendHelper` this is the code

```
function _extendHelper() {
  var args = arguments;
  var res = {};

  if (args && args[0]) {
    for (var j in args) {
      for (var k in args[j]) {
        res[k] = args[j][k];
      }
    }
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: Where are `_extendHelper` and `options`?

Comment: Ah sorry that's just a help to help merge two objects.

Comment: Well, without knowing exactly what that code is, we really can't help because the problem may lie right there since you are using it to configure your XHR.

Comment: Let me give it to you.

Comment: Can you also give us the code you are using to invoke `_ajaxHelper()`?

Comment: try putting `xhr.open(opts.method, opts.url);` before `xhr.withCredentials = opts.withCredentials;`

Comment: also, try `xhr.send` after setting `xhr.on* =`

Comment: though, I don't think either of those are the actual problem - but I don't have IE10 to confirm

Comment: surprisingly that fixed the problem. :-) But I really don't know why

Comment: @toy probably because `open` initialises the XHR instance, and you cannot set options like `withCredentials` before the instance is initialised. (This, of course, is an API design mistake. The `open` args could have gone straight in the constructor).